# Merge ICollection included in detached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have EF entity named Group with ICollection included. This entity is detached. I need to update Group and merge ICollection as well. Add new and delete non exist persons.

I am trying to use this approach, but it adds new Person only.

```
public void GroupUpdate(Group group)
    {
        using (ISEContext context = new ISEContext())
        {                
            context.Attach(group).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        
    }
```

1. I have two persons id DB

   [Andrew, Peter]
2. I removed person Peter and add new person Alice in detached group object

   [Andrew, Alice]
3. After context.SaveChange() I have:

   [Andrew, Peter, Alice]

**What is the best approach to have [Andrew,Alice] in DB?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In detached state you need explicitly set entity state to remove person.

```
public void GroupUpdate(Group group, ICollection<Person> personToRemove)
{
    using (ISEContext context = new ISEContext())
    {                
        context.Attach(group).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.RemoveRange(personsToRemove);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }        
}
```